# Drawing a label on canvas top right corner

Tags: java, swt

How can i draw a label on the top right corner of the canvas and making it stay there as long as i re-size the window?

I tried setting the SWT.RIGHT_TO_LEFT style on the canvas constructor but i don't want the whole canvas to change it's direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you drawing the label? Is this with `GC.drawText` or are you actually using a `Label`?

Comment: Yes.. i'm using a label:Label  alt=new Label(canvas,SWT.RIGHT)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a `Layout` on the `Canvas` and position the label using the layout.

For example:

```
canvas.setLayout(new GridLayout());

...

label.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.END, SWT.TOP, false, false));
```

Do you actually need to use `Canvas`? If you are only using controls as children then `Composite` would be more usually.

Comment: Thank you very much! worked like a charm :) :) :) :)